# Python Selenium Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, macos, selenium, web-scraping, pycharm

I'm trying to use selenium for a python web scraper but when I try to run the program I get the following error:

```
"/Applications/Python 3.8/IDLE.app/Contents/MacOS/Python" "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 52548 --file /Users/xxxx/git/python/python_crawler_example_01/naver_crawling.py
pydev debugger: process 3004 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 192.7142.56)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 72, in start
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home


Process finished with exit code 1
```

It's my error code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

import time
import os, sys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

time.sleep(2)

driver.close()
```

**I'm using macos & pycharm**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJtFi.jpg

Comment: Can you add `print(os.environ['PATH'])` before `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` and check that it really contains path to your chromedriver?

Comment: The resultant value does not correspond to my path. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put the path of your webdriver

example:(if it is in the same directory)

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "/chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: download the chromedriver.exe again maybe that should help

Comment: I did it. But it does not work. And, I'm using macos.

Comment: i haven't tried on mac os but you should check this link out https://www.edureka.co/community/52315/how-to-setup-chrome-driver-with-selenium-on-macos

Comment: Please check the chrome version and chrome driver version