# Python Selenium Help Error - Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, selenium

I haven't programmed in years. I am trying to learn to automate a task for work. I was able to successfully install selenium for Python after having some issues.

This is the simple program I am trying to test to make sure my installation was successful.

Note - I was having issues installing selenium so I had to set the path and some other stuff. So I'm thinking some of those changes might have affected running this Python program.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

When I run the program on the command prompt this is what I get.

```
>py main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jonab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\jonab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\jonab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jonab\Documents\Python Projects\Amazon SC Review Automation\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\jonab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\jonab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I did reference this post and ran their code but got a different error.
[Python Selenium Traceback (most recent call last):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59089684/python-selenium-traceback-most-recent-call-last)

Comment: Are you sure your geckodriver is in PATH.

Comment: `geckodriver` needs to be downloaded separately and then the folder where you've saved it needs to be placed in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: From a Command Prompt, type `where geckodriver`. If you've placed said file in a folder included in your system's PATH environment variable, then you should see the full path to it. Otherwise, you'll get "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)."

Comment: @JustinEzequiel INFO: `Could not find files for the given pattern(s)` is what I'm getting. I downloaded the Windows 64 version from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases I run exe file I only see the following message `1609446253348   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:4444`

Comment: You're not supposed to run that yourself. Selenium would run that for you if it could find where you've saved it. Hence the repeated mention of the PATH environment variable.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel so I would just leave it in the downloads folder? It doesn't go anywhere specific? How do I know what path it's on?

Comment: I put the EXE file exactly where the main Python file folder I am running. It looks like it's working. Thanks.